# Constant first row of a .csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a Python code which is logging some data into a .csv file.

```
logging_file = 'test.csv'
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
f = open(logging_file, 'a')
f.write('\n "{:%H:%M:%S}",{},{}'.format(dt,x,y,))
```

The above code is the core part and this produces continuous data in .csv file as

```
"00:34:09" ,23.05,23.05
"00:36:09" ,24.05,24.05
"00:38:09" ,26.05,26.05

... etc.,
```

Now I wish to add the following lines in first row of this data. time, data1,data2.I expect output as

```
time, data1, data2
"00:34:09" ,23.05,23.05
"00:36:09" ,24.05,24.05
"00:38:09" ,26.05,26.05

... etc.,
```

I tried many ways. Those ways not produced me the result as preferred format.But I am unable to get my expected result.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: "I tried many ways." Those being ... ?

Comment: As soon as you open the file for the very first time, write that line to it.

Comment: @wwii I tried that way too. But it returns just empty string.

Comment: You may not be giving us enough information to help you. Maybe don't worry about it and *add* that line when you read and use the file.?

Comment: I recommend you [take a look at this](https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/node304.html) - maybe you don't want to write your own logger - Python already got that for you.

Comment: While adding something to the beginning of the file after it's had some other data added to it is possible, but somewhat involved. It would be much easier to put the header row in when the file is initially created. You say you tried that, but "it returns just empty string"—_what_ returns the empty string? Suggest you should [edit] your question and show how you were trying to do it and the error or incorrect results you got.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a class specifically for creating and managing logs.
Have it initialize a file, on creation, with the expected first line (don't forget a \n character!), and keep track of any necessary information about that log(the name of the log it created, where it is, etc). You can then have the class 'write' to the log (append the log, really), you can create new logs as necessary, and, you can have it check for existing logs, and make decisions about either updating what is existing, or scrapping it and starting over.

Comment: If anything, you should recommend he uses one of the many existing logging packages. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @displayname You make a good point, but if they are having a problem with a self-created log, the practice of creating one from scratch will help with managing files through a class, as well as keeping tracking of it. It's also likely that an existing logging package is more bells and whistles than is necessary (although, using a package may be more ideal simply because of the likelihood of errors is reduced)